# How/Why is my php working if brew services says none

Tags: php, homebrew, zsh

So im trying to understand why is my php code is working. Recently upon every `brew update && brew upgrade` php seems to break. when I run  `php artisan [something]` an error occurs, that is easily fixed by `brew reinstall php`

I noticed that when I `sudo launchctl list | grep php` I get in return `- 78  homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4` but php@7.4 is no longer installed,yet is the only reference I have... `ps aux | grep php` shows nothing `ps -ax | grep php` nothing as well, `brew services list` and `sudo brew services list` shows both php status as none...

when I run `php -v` and `php-fpm -v` it works, only thing is I have /usr/local/php/bin in my path...

so why is my php -v working and upon brew update && brew upgrade it breaks?